# Slow EF query grouping data by Month/Year

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a record set of approximetly 1 million records. I'm trying to query the records to report monthly figures.

The following MySQL query executes in about 0.3 seconds

```
SELECT SUM(total), MONTH(create_datetime), YEAR(create_datetime) 
FROM orders GROUP BY MONTH(create_datetime), YEAR(create_datetime)
```

However I am unable to figure out an entity framework lambda expression that can execute any near as fast

The only statement I have come up with that actually works is

```
var monthlySales = db.Orders
                     .Select(c => new
                     {
                         Total = c.Total,
                         CreateDateTime = c.CreateDateTime
                     })
                     .GroupBy(c => new { c.CreateDateTime.Year, c.CreateDateTime.Month })
                     .Select(c => new
                     {
                         CreateDateTime = c.FirstOrDefault().CreateDateTime,
                         Total = c.Sum(d => d.Total)
                     })
                     .OrderBy(c => c.CreateDateTime)
                     .ToList();
```

But it is horribly slow.

How can I get this query to execute as quickly as it does directly in MySQL

Comment: What is the actual SQL command being sent to the server ? We need to understand if the speed issue is server side, or client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this setup which executes quickly

```
            var monthlySales = db.Orders
                 .GroupBy(c => new { Year = c.CreateDateTime.Year, Month = c.CreateDateTime.Month })
                 .Select(c => new
                 {
                     Month = c.Key.Month,
                     Year = c.Key.Year,
                     Total = c.Sum(d => d.Total)
                 })
                 .OrderByDescending(a => a.Year)
                 .ThenByDescending(a => a.Month)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, that's how you should do it. Similar to my answer, but I used LINQ which I think is more readable and shorter.

Comment: @RacilHilan if he moved the 2 lines of ordering code, the code is almost the same in length. Using query or method syntax is just a preference. In many cases query syntax is shorter (but not in this case) but in many cases we ***have to*** use method syntax. To me method syntax looks better in term of OOP and fluent syntax, query looks better in term of SQL-like syntax.

Comment: @KingKing There is nothing in what you said that I disagree with :-). I clearly said ***that's how you should do it***, but I just wanted to make a note that the two answers are similar, so OP and others can choose what they like. The rest was my own opinion so I said ***I think***. I personally always use the query syntax except two cases: 1) when we have to, like you said. 2) When I only need one or two method call(s) for the obvious reason that it is shorter and clearer than the query in this case.

Answer (score 0):

When you do ".ToList()" in the middle of query (before doing grouping) EF will effectively query all orders from database in memory and then do grouping in C#. Depending on amount of data in your table, that can take a while and I think this is why your query is so slow.

Try to rewrite your query having only 1 expression that enumerates results (ToList, ToArray, AsEnumerable)

Comment: After removing the initial .ToList(), the query speed didn't seem to change at all (roughly 1 minute)

Comment: Have you checked SQL that is generated by query now? ((ObjectQuery)yorquery).ToTraceString() At the moment I don't have Mysql box to test for sure, but I think it should work if you start with db.Orders.GroupBy() and then do select from this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var monthlySales = from c in db.Orders
                   group c by new { y = c.CreateDateTime.Year, m = c.CreateDateTime.Month } into g
                   select new {
                       Total = c.Sum(t => t.Total),
                       Year = g.Key.y,
                       Month = g.Key.m }).ToList();
```